# Bem naming conventions

Tags: html, css, bem

im using the BEM naming convention within a small project and having some slight difficulty in deciding between element and modifier names.

I'm currently working on a **hero/splash** section of the website. **see image below**. [image]

Heres my current code -

```
<div class="hero hero__project">

    <div class="grid">

        <h1 class="hero__project__title">Final Year Project</h1>

        <div class="hero__project__meta">
            <p>Published<span>23 Oct 2014</span></p>
            <p>Applictions <span>Unity3d, Photoshop, 3ds max</span></p>
        </div>

        <p class="hero__project__summary">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in </p>

    </div>  

</div>
```

My question is - Do you understand what the piece of markup is doing? and is it in line with them BEM methodology. Thanks

Comment: Its not the question being asked but, my personal opinion, dashes are much more readable then underscores. `hero__project__summary` vs `hero-project-summary`

Comment: Hey, I agree with you!but i'm going to be strict at this present time as i'm still learning BEM. I'll start to implement my own ideas once I get the full grasp it.

Comment: try this project to getbem.com

Comment: @VladimirStarkov Thanks I will have a read!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I understand BEM, I would say your naming does not make sense. Your Block (or module) would be your `.hero`. Your Elements would be your main components of your block (i.e. project-title, project-meta, etc). If you needed a modifier on your block for a different state, you could add one in addition to your block (e.g. `class=".hero .hero--isHidden`)

```
<div class="hero">
  <div class="grid">
    <h1 class="hero__project-title"></h1>
    <div class="hero__project-meta"></div>
    <p class="hero__project-summary"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

For more in-depth info checkout http://csswizardry.com/2013/01/mindbemding-getting-your-head-round-bem-syntax/

Comment: Hey man, i'm currently working on the **project page** of the website hence the reason for .hero__project as my main block......(for page specific styling). other than thanks for the link, that was helpful.

Comment: I think the point is to have `.hero` as a module that could be used on any page. If there was a particular reason `.hero` is different on the project page you could I guess use a modifier (i.e. `class=".hero .hero--project`) but keep all else the same.

Comment: I initially went with that! but became confused, which is why i ended up here. Thanks

Comment: How about my other class names. Would they remain the same? eg **hero__project-title** vs **hero--project-title**?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question regarding the other names, I guess I would modify my answer slightly. Again, only using the `--project` modifier to style the other elements if they are indeed different than a `hero` on another page.

```
<div class="hero hero--project">
  <div class="grid">
    <h1 class="hero__title"></h1>
    <div class="hero__meta"></div>
    <p class="hero__summary"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to BEM and trying to wrap my head around it all. I read one of the rules for BEM was no nested selectors. So based off the 2nd answer, let's say we style the hero title to be black but style project hero titles to be red. Would the CSS look like this?

```
.hero__title { color: #000; }
.hero--project .hero__title { color: #cc0000; }
```